# Accessing memory used by other program

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

Today I've a weird question again (at least to me it is). I'm experimenting more into pointers and an idea arouse in my mind as follows:

#### The Code (only a portion of it)

```
int * firefoxmemory = (char*) 0x11111111 //this is just an example of address.
*firefoxmemory = 200;
```

#### The Question:

In the above code, I try to access memory used by firefox (I use a memory editor to view the address) and after that change its corresponding value. But when I try to do so my program crashes.

Why does this happen to my program? Is there some special code used by Firefox to prevent a 3rd party program from tampering with its memory? Or it's done by the Windows and Intel hardware DEP?

If the above action is prevented by DEP, why does some memory editing software still work, like cheat engines that can alter values in memory?

Comment: You can't access another processes' memory like that (Ok, unless you're programming AmigaOS).

Comment: The OS will prevent programs from accessing each other's memory. This won't work. If you want to access memory between programs, you need something like shared memory.

Comment: You can use windows functions to examine memory of a different program, you can't just dereference it

Comment: Why cheat engine can access the memory and change the value??

Comment: Only amigaOS allow this operation??Can i do it in linux??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It crashes because `0x11111111` does not point to a valid address within your app's memory space.

As for cheat engine, there are a couple of ways to access another program's memory:

1) run code inside the target process's memory space. There are various ways to inject code into another process using `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `CreateRemoteThread()`.

2) use `ReadProcessMemory()` and `WriteProcessMemory()`

Comment: That's mean windows effort in preventing hacking by using virtual addressing rendered to by useless since there're methods to circumvent it

Comment: Virtual addressing is not meant to prevent hacking. It allows the OS to manage physical memory better, and ensures that a crashed process does not affect other processes. For instance, before virtual addressing was introduced in Windows 95, a crashed process could take out the entire OS. The Windows API specifically exposes functions for accessing memory, allocating/freeing memory, and running code across process boundaries, so it is not trying to prevent hacking.

Answer (score 10):

Modern operating system use virtual addressing - so each program has what it thinks is the same address space. The OS maps this to real memory addresses.

So for example Firefox has a string located at 0x100, you program also has a string located at 0x100 - both of these are virtual memory addresses - the OS/CPU maps these addresses to real physical RAM - and it keeps them separate from each other - to avoid exactly the hacking technique you describe.

Comment: Why cheat engine can access the memory and change the value??

Comment: Well that would depend on the user (aka root) running the operation. This is important in protecting the root user of your system to stop this type of hacking.

Comment: if it's using virtual address , that's mean my program could only access its own virtual space , but why the above program would crash since I'm not accessing the physical address space of firefox but instead it's just the virtual space of my program??Besides that i still don't understand how cheat engine manage to circumvent the prevention and being able to access the process(e.g firefox) directly and change its value since cheat engine is just a program just like the program i write.

Comment: Windows is a special child. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Another way to share memory between process in win32 is to use memory-mapped files:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx

But similarly to `ReadProcessMemory()` and `WriteProcessMemory()` this method requires support of 2 process.

There is no legal way to read memory of a process if the process doesn't provide any permissions to do it. It's a basement of secure multiprocessing in all modern operation systems.