# Is there any way by which a process P2 can access the local variable of another process P1?

Tags: c++, memory-management, process

Suppose there are two processes P1, P2(which is a virus) in linux.
Can P2 access a local varable  (say x) of P1 ?

On searching on web, I found that since the addresses used in processes are logical addresses, P2 can't access the local variable 'x' of P1.

But I am wondering if P2 generates random addresses and one of which resolves to the same physical address as of 'x' then can't it access it ?

 Is it really possible for P2 to access 'x' of P1 ? 
If yes, how? (If it can be accessed through any tricks, please let me know)  
And if no, why?

P1 code :

```
int main() {
  int x = 20;
  return 0;
}
```

p2 code :

```
int main() {
  /*
  generate random addresses and access them.
  one of them might resolve to physical address of 'x' in P1
  */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Processes generally have isolated memory - even without ASLR. However, there are ways to use “shared memory” (hint: keyword).

Comment: Why would P2 generate random addresses? Unless are you asking if P1 is vulnerable to an attack in this way?

Comment: @Chipster "Unless are you asking if P1 is vulnerable to an attack in this way?" ==> Yes I meant this.

Comment: @user2864740 "However, there are ways to use “shared memory”" ==> That is a legit way of sharing memory. Is there any way to access 'x' from P2 without using any legitimate way of sharing memory?

Comment: Kabul, details depend on environment- take a number of “game cheat” programs as a (a “non-malicious”) example. In older-times these were heavily based around memory modifications. Usually requires special elevation and support/feasibility varies. There are also ways to “hook” into a running process, such that the memory access is not actually across process boundaries.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191801/accessing-memory-used-by-other-program. It might be a duplicate, or at least might have some useful information.

Comment: @Chipster Thanks, will check out the link.

Comment: Also [this](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-access-the-memory-address-of-a-variable-in-another-program-using-C-C++) it might answer your question.

Comment: @Chipster Sure, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detailed mechanics depend on the OS, but with modern CPU architectures that use [virtual memory](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-memory-operating-systems/):

- each process has its own [virtual address space](https://manybutfinite.com/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/).
- the hardware organizes the mapping between the virtual addresses and the real physical addresses.
- any access to an unmapped virtual address will raise an error that will be caught

So if P1 uses an address 0x200,  and if P2 would know this address and decide to use it to inject some stuff, this would not work.  Because the virtual address 0x200 of one process is not the same than virtual address 0x200 of the other address. No address is shared between these process (except in the OS address space and this is well protected).  So there's (in principle) no way for P2 to corrupt P1.

It is possible to use some special functions from the OS to share some memory, either via [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) or via [memory mapped files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).  But both processes need to cooperate in order to share memory.

Finally, depending on the privileges of P2, P2 could request access from the OS to the address space of P1. With windows it's the API functions [`ReadProcessMemory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) and [`WriteProcessMemory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory), and under linux, it's access to the [/dev/mem](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html) device corresponding to the physical memory.  But these privileges are given only to trustworthy processes run by trustworthy users.  In principle normal processes of normal users shouldn't have these very sensitive privileges... So your P1 should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Processes in linux run in protected mode. This means that a process has a virtual address and not a physical address.

The answer to question is yes because linux offers methods to write and read memory of another process.

This can be done by writing and reading the file /proc/%ld/mem where %ld is id of the process.

If you want to know more you can visit: https://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/09/03/

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a process does not exist in the C++ language. There is no standard way to communicate between processes in C++.

There are however platform specific ways of inter process communication (IPC) provided by operating systems. A widely used IPC method are network sockets which can be used for commincation between not only processes within the same system, but also between processes on different systems connected by a network.